# Python: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I have a 100 lines, 3 years old python scraper that now bug. Starting lines are:

```
import urllib, re, os, sys, time    # line 1: import modules
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) # line 2: all works in script's folder > relative address
# (rest of my script here!)
```

When run,

```
$cd /my/folder/
$python script.py
```

I receive the error:

```
python script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

**How should I read this error and what to do ?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Have you noticed that you don't get the error if you run

```
python ./script.py
```

instead of

```
python script.py
```

This is because `sys.argv[0]` will read `./script.py` in the former case, which gives `os.path.dirname` something to work with.  When you don't specify a path, `sys.argv[0]` reads simply `script.py`, and `os.path.dirname` cannot determine a path.

Answer (score 30):

I had this error because I was providing a string of arguments to `subprocess.call` instead of an array of arguments. To prevent this, use `shlex.split`:

```
import shlex, subprocess
command_line = "ls -a"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
p = subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Comment: thanks. it's necessary in python 2.7 but not anymore in python 3

Comment: I am having the same error but i tried with shlex.split and also passing an array to subprocess.popen.What i am trying to do is switch to a new directory and running a python script in a new shell in linux.

command_to_run=shlex.split("cd .. && cd Adapter_Main && python2 client.py")
subprocess.Popen(command_to_run,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

This is all in python2 and in this i am getting the OS error.No such file or directory.I have checked the command in normal shell and this command is working absolutely correctly.

Answer (score 19):

Use `os.path.abspath()`:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])))
```

`sys.argv[0]` in your case is *just* a script name, no directory, so `os.path.dirname()` returns an empty string.

[`os.path.abspath()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) turns that into a proper absolute path with directory name.

Comment: Probably reviving an old thread, but I wanted to add that this answer is very interesting. I have two scripts in the same folder, same permissions, both use `argparse` and are executable via CLI. One doesn't exhibit any issues but the other gives the same error of `No such file or directory`. If I use your solution I can run the problematic script just fine using `python foo.py` but not from `./foo.py`. I'm very curious as to why this is

Comment: @KamikazeRusher: I would be too, but without further details I can't help you there. Perhaps post that as a new question?

Comment: I don't think there's much more detail I can give anyways. Thank you for responding, however I believe the matter is trivial for the time being and doesn't warrant its own question quite yet. I just found it interesting that even under identical circumstances you can still find inconsistencies like this

Comment: @KamikazeRusher: I'd dispute that the circumstances are identical if you get apparently inconsistent results. *Something* is different between the two cases!

Answer (score 0):

try using otatools command : **m -j otatools**
It worked in my case.

running the command m -j otatools starts the build process for creating an OTA update package for an Android ROM built from the AOSP source code.

Answer (score -1):

I was compiling the android code v4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, when I met the same problem of Python, no such file or directory.

It ends as I installed below libraries. So I think maybe it will help someone at some occasion. The python script takes it for granted that some lib exists in the system.

```
sudo apt install gperf
sudo apt install  libxml2-utils
sudo apt install libbison-dev
```

Comment: Your specific use-case and error has nothing to do with the one presented here... It makes no sense to need to install external libraries in order to solve this problem... See the accepted answer to see what was the problem here...