# Python: Selenium cannot create instance of Firefox WebDriver on OS

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data from a URL with dynamic content and learned Selenium can do the task.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

The 4 lines above gives me

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I googled and seems that others have encountered similar issues but none of the solutions I found work. Some seem to be for Windows and others seem to be for Java rather than Python.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, I got the same error. But, if you just want to use selenium to open up Firefox browser and go from there, simply use this:

```
  from selenium import webdriver
  browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  browser.get("http://www.google.com")
```

It will trigger an initial web browser and open up a webpage.

Comment: Hi Jin, I tried this earlier and it gives error 'OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory'   Seems I need to put something as webdrive.Firefox('something')

Comment: Hi Camuslu, since I don't have that error, not very sure how to fix it, but I assume it's because os.path has not been specified. I checked out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725273/python-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory, thinking maybe you could try to run:   python ./script.py

Answer (score 0):

The following line causes the problem:

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS')
```

Make sure to provide the correct path of the binary on the **filesystem**, not in your application launcher, i.e.

```
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
```