# Renaming files in Python: No such file or directory

Tags: python

If I try to rename files in a directory, for some reason I get an error.
I think the problem may be that I have not inserted the directory in the proper format ?

Additional info:
python 2 &
linux machine

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Though it prints the directories content just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
import os

for i in os.listdir("/home/fanna/Videos/strange"):
    #print str(i)
    os.rename(i, i[:-17])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: OSError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory: ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15725273/python-oserror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Are you in the correct directory?  That is, is your python working directory /home/fanna/Videos/strange.  If not, concatenate that with the file name

Answer (score 10):

`os.rename()` is expecting the full path to the file you want to rename. `os.listdir` only returns the filenames in the directory. Try this

```
import os
baseDir = "/home/fanna/Videos/strange/"
for i in os.listdir( baseDir ):
    os.rename( baseDir + i, baseDir + i[:-17] )
```

Comment: This solved my problem!! did not realise it did not include the path as well!

Comment: Glad it worked out. I've edited the answer to be more explicit on what os.listdir returns. And remember, you can accept the answer that worked best for you with the green checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is a file `/home/fanna/Videos/strange/name_of_some_video_file.avi`, and you're running the script from `/home/fanna`.

`i` is `name_of_some_video_file.avi` (the name of the file, not including the full path to it). So when you run

```
os.rename(i, i[:-17])
```

you're saying

```
os.rename("name_of_some_video_file.avi", "name_of_some_video_file.avi"[:-17])
```

Python has no idea that these files came from `/home/fanna/Videos/strange`. It resolves them against the currrent working directory, so it's looking for `/home/fanna/name_of_some_video_file.avi`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late but the reason it happens is that `os.listdir` only lists the items inside that directory, but the working directory remains the location where the python script is located.

So to fix the issue add:

```
os.chdir(your_directory_here)
```

just before the for loop where `your_directory_here` is the directory you used for `os.listdir`.