# os.rename() for file extensions winerror2

Tags: python, file-rename

I have been looking for solutions for a while but no luck. I apologise if this has already been solved.

Trying to rename file extensions from .ods to .xls across all files in a directory:

```
import os

def Convert(dirpath):
for ws in os.listdir(dirpath):
    splitfile = os.path.splitext(ws)
    os.rename(ws, splitfile[0] + '.xls')

Convert('my_directory')
```

This returns the error:
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'filename_that_exists.ods' -> 'filename_that_exists.xls'

Comment: Related: [renaming in python (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375483/renaming-files-in-python-no-such-file-or-directory); basically you need the full path on the renaming method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this might solve your problem

```
    os.rename(os.path.join(directory,name), 
              os.path.join(directory,'0'+name))
```

Comment: This absolutely worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome Dear for any further help you can get in touch to me from here http://maskottchen.tech/